# Table sorter AJAX based column filter

Tags: ajax, tablesorter

Can I do ajax based filter search on table sorter? I'd like this to update my table as well or if anyway to bind the onchange event with all the filter columns?

Below is my code:

```
.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: [ 'stickyHeaders', 'columnSelector','filter'],
    textExtraction: function(node, table, cellIndex){
        return $(node).text().replace(/\s'/g,'');
    },
    headers: {0: { filter: false},6: { filter: false},7: { filter: false},8: { filter: false}},
    initialized: function(){
        lastSearch = $table.data('lastSearch');
    },
    widgetOptions : {


      // Use the $.tablesorter.storage utility to save the most recent filters
      filter_saveFilters : false,
      // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filters
      filter_reset : 'button.reset',
      // add custom selector elements to the filter row
      filter_formatter : {
        /*0 : function($cell, indx){
          return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {     
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear : true
          });
        },*/
        // Alphanumeric (match)
        4 : function($cell, indx){
          return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
            match : true,         // adds "filter-match" to header
           // cellText : 'Select: ', // Cell text
            width: '90%',         // adjusted width to allow for cell text
            value: [<%=createdBy%>], // initial values
            placeholder: "Search.."

          });
        },
        5 : function($cell, indx){
          return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.select2( $cell, indx, {
            match : true,         // adds "filter-match" to header
           // cellText : 'Select: ', // Cell text
            width: '90%',         // adjusted width to allow for cell text
            value: [<%=actions%>], // initial values
            placeholder: "Search.."
          });
        },
      /*7 : function($cell, indx){
          return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {
            // from : '08/01/2013', // default from date
            // to   : '1/18/2014',  // default to date
            dateFormat : 'dd/MM/yyyy',
            changeMonth : true,
            changeYear : true,
            cellText : ""
          });
        }*/
      },



      // option added in v2.16.0
      filter_selectSource : {
        // Alphanumeric match (prefix only)
        // added as select2 options (you could also use select2 data option)
        4 : function(table, column) {
          return [<%=createdBy%>];
        },
        5 : function(table, column) {
          return [<%=actions%>];
        },
      }

    /*  filter_placeholder : {
        from : 'From...',
        to   : 'To...'
      }*/

    },

  });
```